# Get value in function odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I need get value from current form field:

Ex:

```py
time = fields.Many2one('time.project', domain=lambda self: self._get_time())
vehicle_id = fields.Many2one('fleet.vehicle', 'Vehicle', required=True)
def _get_time(self):
   vehicle_val = Get selected vehicle id from field vehicle_id on current form.

   times = self.env['project.vehicle'].search([('vehicle_id', '=', vehicle_val)
```

Comment: Is vehicle_val a field in the same form

Comment: vehicle_id = fields.Many2one(......)  is field.....

Comment: What do you mean by vehicle_val =? What is the domain that you looking for

Comment: In my case vehicle_val = self.vehicle_id  or  user_val = self.user_id ....

Comment: I want selected value from field put in search .search([('vehicle_id', '=', ???)  self.vehicle_id  not working return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should use `onchange` to change the domain every 
time the value of the vehicle is changed.

```py
@api.onchange('vehicle_id')
def dynamic_domain(self):
    vehicle_val =??
    times = self.env['project.vehicle'].search([('vehicle_id', '=', vehicle_val)])
    return {'domain': {'times': [('id', 'in', times.ids)]}}
```

Hope this helps you.